# Proguard Obfuscation for JAR files

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I know how to obfuscate executable jar files due to the fact that it has a main class. But I'm trying to create my API (It's already done) and I just need to obfuscate the code. The problem is that whenever I try obfuscate the jar file using Proguard (A well known java obfuscator) it gives me an error about something to do with the 'keep'. I am running the proguard-gui from Proguard and in Eclipse, I exported the project as a normal jar file (not executable) and I'm trying to obfuscate that jar file. Also, I am not including the .classpath and .project files inside my jar file either. If anyone could please help/guide me in obfuscating non-executable jar files in Proguard, it would be very useful and appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I'm using Proguard's GUI to obfuscate, not anything to do with the command line.

Image of problem:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your config file for Proguard, you need to specify which classes you want to keep, otherwise Proguard will just reduce away everything.
The most common kind of keep line looks something like:

```
-keep my.applications.package.*
```

or

```
-keep my.applications.package.MainClass
```

You can find examples of configuration files on the [Proguard webpage](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html)

Comment: There is no main class though, it's an external library. :P That's why I'm getting kind of confused on what to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that there is no main method in any of my classes.

Comment: There's an example for that on the proguard page as well under "8. A typical library".

Comment: I tried that and it obfuscated public methods and classes of a jar that was built with no third party libraries. In spite of using the example config file, it seemed to treat my jar like an application and not a library.

Answer (score 3):

Cfr ProGuard manual > Examples > [A typical library](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#library)

The GUI has a checkbox for processing libraries.

Comment: The reference is well popular. I do not see any such check box, could you please share the image or reference.